# Recorded a Macro to Import a File in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

I'm able to import a file from my disk using "File Import".
I tried to do the process while recording a macro.
I did "File", "Import", then chose "Upload new file" and picked something like "C:\mydir\CurrentPriceFile.csv".

While recording it seemed to work, but playback does nothing.

The macro it recorded only shows this:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function ImportCurrentPricesFile() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('K4').activate();
};
```

Is it not possible for it to record the "File Import"?

What alternatives do I have? I saw somewhere else that I could probably use "=importData()" but then I have to put the file on a webserver.

Comment: Why would you need a macro to import a file to google sheets? Just stick a spreadsheet in your Google Drive folder while the app is running and it should be available in Google Sheets, right?

Comment: XY problem, please explain your goal instead of your proposed solution

Comment: @Gantendo I run a Python program that I can schedule daily to scrape data from a website and stores it in a CSV.  I want to re-import the same file at any time with a "one click" solution, on one of the sheets in my bigger spreadsheet.  
Other cells do price =vlookup on this data.

Comment: If the CSV file is inside your Google Drive folder, and the Google Drive app is running, it will sync the file to the cloud when your Python program updates it, right? If you want to do it from Python you could look at something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-L1NKoEi10 & 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDD9pwmL_jg

Comment: I run OneDrive and Dropbox already, I don't think I run a Google Drive sync. But perhaps I could use an URL from OneDrive or Dropbox, but then it would make me sign in each time.  I could explore uploading to Google Drive from the Python program, but I think that involves OAUTH which might not be so easy.  Actually AWS S3 might be the best place I could upload it, then use =ImportData.  But all that sounds much more involved that my initial idea of automating File Import.

Comment: https://www.google.com/intl/en/drive/download/ It is pretty similar to something like Dropbox

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks I will check videos and link tomorrow.  Been on the computer too long today.  I don't really want all my GoogleDrive on my PC and more CPU to sync it, on top of what I'm already running.

Comment: You could configure the Google Drive app to only sync that one file, and leave the rest of your files in the cloud and not on your computer. That shouldn't take much resources. https://i.imgur.com/BjBeZPZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Sheets macro recorder writes a JavaScript function using Google Apps Script classes. Only some Google Sheets user interface commands are available on Google Apps Script. File > Import is not one of them.

In general, Class SpreadsheetApp and Class DriveApp can't access the user's local environment, i.e., file system, web browser, network, etc. Other relevant classes are Session, Script and Utilities, among others, can't access the user's local environment either.

To use Google Apps Script, you should upload the file to the web, Google Drive is the most convenient option as you could use Class DriveApp and Class SpreadsheetApp together to add the data from the CSV file to a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Using Google Drive for Desktop could make uploading the file easier.

If you use another service to host your file, like OneDrive, you might use Class FetchApp to get the file. If the file is private, you might have to use OAuth2. Fortunately, Google has created and maintained a Google Apps Script library.

## Workarounds

### Using IMPORTDATA built-in function

If the CSV file is hosted online, public, and not too big, it might be imported using IMPORTDATA's built-in Google Sheets function. The data will be imported according to the Google Sheets refresh algorithms.

Please note that there are posts on the web about IMPORTDATA occasionally returning errors even when there are no changes on the spreadsheet or the CSV file, probably due to glitches in the network connection, the Google data centers or the Google Sheets software.

### Creating a "web app" using Google Apps Script

Google Apps Script could create dialogs, sidebars, and standalone web apps. These web apps are enclosed in several IFRAME layers that allow code to run on the client side. This makes it possible to add a form to upload a file, among other things, but this might be too convoluted for your needs.

Comment: I got it to work with DropBox: 
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xxxxsecretxxxx/Prices_MostRecent.csv?rlkey=xxxsecret&raw=1")
You just have to turn on sharing, get the link and add raw=1 at the end.  The file is public, but only people who have the link can see it.

Comment: @NealWalters Thanks for sharing. I hope that you are aware of using IMPORTDATA about the implications of using it, as there is low to no-control for end-users about when the data is imported.